# the best pre emphasis for MMSE equalizer

Tags: digital-communications, filter-design, bandwidth

The system consists of multiple low-pass filter and noise, $h_1$, $h_2$, $h_3$, ..., $n_1$, $n_2$, $n_3$, ...

At the transmitter, the power of signal is fixed; and at the receiver, MMSE equalizer is used to minimize the MSE.

My question is that if we can pre-emphasis the signal in the transmitter to improve the overall performance. If the distribution of signal and noise is known, what is the optimal pre-emphasis system?

Answer (score 3):

welcome.

As MMSE estimators are unbiased, try reducing [Cramér–Rao bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Bound_on_the_variance_of_biased_estimators) and *maybe* your MMSE equalizer can achieve a better performance. Note that in general the MMSE estimator is known to be *asymptotically efficient*.

Note also that you must specify criteria before say something is "optimal". Even so, it is usually not easy to prove the optimality.